# rtsp server forwarding

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, rtsp

So I am trying to stream a webcam feed from my computer to my android phone.  I am using a simple forwarding server to connect the two so that I don't have to worry about home network IP firewalls ect.  I am using FMJ to capture the video feed and was thinking rtsp protocol would be best because android supports reading it.  My problem is I dont know how to forward the information via the server, is it as simple as forwarding UDP packets?  all programs involved are implemented in java btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). It is very easy to create an RTSP server with this library. For hints see the sources [here](http://code.google.com/p/mobicents/).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can port my library which is written in C#

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

CodeProject article @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp